# Getting Variable Names for X-Axis when Looping in ggplot?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm wondering if there is any way to insert the actual corresponding variable on the x-axis for each graph. In my actual dataset, I have 15 predictors. As it is not, for every graph, on axis, I just crime crime[,i].

Thanks!

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
y<- c(1,5,6,2,5,10) # response 
x1<- c(2,12,8,1,16,17) # predictor 
x2<- c(2,14,5,1,17,17)

crime <- data.frame(x1,x2,y)

for (i in 1:ncol(crime)){ 
  print(ggplot(crime, aes(x = crime[, i], y = y))+
    geom_point()) 
  Sys.sleep(2) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to get the `names` based on the index, then convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
for (i in 1:2){ # the first two columns are the 'x' columns
   print(ggplot(crime, aes(x = !! rlang::sym(names(crime)[i]), y = y))+
     geom_point()) 
     Sys.sleep(2) 
   }
```

---

Or another option is to keep the OP's code as such while adding a layer with `xlab`

```
for (i in 1:2){ # the first two columns are the 'x' columns
   print(ggplot(crime, aes(x = crime[,i], y = y))+
          geom_point() +
          xlab(names(crime)[i])) 
    Sys.sleep(2) 
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used rlang before. Will explore this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over column names in `for` loop and use them with `.data` in `aes`.

```
library(ggplot2)

for (col in names(crime)){ 
  print(ggplot(crime, aes(x = .data[[col]], y = y)) +  geom_point()) 
  Sys.sleep(2) 
}
```